# What memory settings make a reasonable compromise for OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice, ubuntu-10.10

Regarding the settings at the OpenOffice dialog:

Tools - Options - OpenOffice.org - Memory

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 and I have 4GB on a 2.8GHz quad core x86-64 architecture machine.  I would consider my Office software needs to be typical.

What is a typical and reasonable set of configs for OpenOffice? For example: how much memory is a good compromise for a typical Graphics Cache object (configured via Graphics Cache/Memory per object)? What are good compromise values for "Cache for inserted objects/number of objects" and "Graphics cache/use for OpenOffice.org"?